# Producer failures inside executeInTransaction

Tags: transactions, spring-kafka

In my application 
1) we are consuming from a topic (firstTopic) , 
2)  process the request by calling some 3rd party services  and  (We have a retryTemplate here for exponential backoff)
3)  submit to second topic (secondtopic).

We are also manually updating the offset after successful submission. KafkaTransactionManager is used to maintain the transactions. Since the message is posted to firstTopic through a RestController our @Transactional starts there and ends when the offset is updated. We are using executeInTransaction() for this.

KafkaConfiguration

```java
@Bean
public ProducerFactory producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 10);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, User> defaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    defaultKafkaProducerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("trans");
    //defaultKafkaProducerFactory.transactionCapable();
    return defaultKafkaProducerFactory;
    //return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}
```

```java
/**
 * New configuration for the consumerFactory added
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, User> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "firstTopic-group");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<User>(User.class));
}


@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, User>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
    factory.setRetryTemplate(kafkaRetry());
    factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
    factory.setErrorHandler(getErrorHandler());
    factory.setRecoveryCallback(retryContext -> {
        //implement the logic to decide the action after all retries are over.
        ConsumerRecord consumerRecord = (ConsumerRecord) retryContext.getAttribute("record");
        System.out.println("Recovery is called for message  " + consumerRecord.value());
        return Optional.empty();
    });

    return factory;
}


public RetryTemplate kafkaRetry() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(10 * 1000);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(1);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(60 * 1000);       // original 25 * 60 * 1000
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(4);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    return retryTemplate;
}


public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler getErrorHandler() {
    SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Exception thrownException,
                           List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,
                           Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                           MessageListenerContainer container) {
            //super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
            if (!records.isEmpty()) {
                ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = records.get(0);
                String topic = record.topic();
                long offset = record.offset();
                int partition = record.partition();

                if (thrownException instanceof DeserializationException) {
                    System.out.println("------1111------deserialization exception ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("------xxxx------Record is empty ");
                    consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(topic, partition), offset);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("------4444------Record is empty ");
            }

        }
    };

    return errorHandler;
}
```

Rest Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("accounts")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;


    @PostMapping("/users")
    @Transactional
    public String postComments(@RequestParam("firstName") final String firstName,
                               @RequestParam("lastName") final String lastName,
                               @RequestParam("userName") final String userName) {

        List<String> accountTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
        kafkaTemplate.send("firstTopic", new User(firstName, lastName, userName));

        return "Message sent to the Error queue";
    }

}
```

service

```java
@Service
public class KafkaMessageConsumerService {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;

    int index = 0;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "firstTopic", groupId = "firstTopic-group")
    //@Transactional
    public void onCustomerMessage(User user, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {            


        kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(t -> {
            int number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);


            t.send("secondtopic", user);
            if (number % 2 == 0 || number % 2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("about to ack");
                throw new RuntimeException(" Modulus is zero ");
            }
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();

            return true;
        }); 
    }


}
```

We have also added a producer retry (10) to the secondtopic. In executeInTransaction()  where we are  producing to secondtopic  we are testing producer failures by throwing a manual exception between the send to secondtopic and offset commit.  What we observe is that when the exception is thrown  (inside executeInTransaction()) it retries the  logic outside the executeInTransaction() and after 10 retries  throws this exception

2020-06-02 11:10:34.869 ERROR 685813 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor    : Backoff FixedBackOff{interval=0, currentAttempts=10, maxAttempts=9} exhausted for ConsumerRecord(topic = firstTopic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 4, CreateTime = 1591114230710, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 61, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = com.barade.sandesh.springKafka.model.User@4d4040ae)

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.barade.sandesh.springKafka.service.KafkaMessageConsumerService.onCustomerMessage(com.barade.sandesh.springKafka.model.User,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment) throws java.lang.Exception' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException:  Modulus is zero

Is this the correct way of addressing the producer failures ?

Is there a way to   capture the exception after the 10th retry and process the message according to business rule ? Can we keep 2 RetryTemplates and SeekToErrorHandlers ?

Comment: This description is incomplete: 1) there is no `executeInTransaction` in any of the above code. 2) There is no listener shown at all and no code calling an Acknowledgment. Also provide version information.

Comment: i was getting formatting issue when submitting the request, must have been removed during the edits. I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `executeInTransaction` there (unless you really want to perform the publishing in a different transaction). The listener container has already started a transaction.

Furthermore, the `acknowledge()` sends the offsets to the container's transaction, not the one started by the template.

This could be why you are getting strange errors on the acknowledgment; I don't know.

Simply remove the `executeInTransaction` and the template will participate in the container's transaction.

Comment: I removed the executeInTransaction , yet get the same error, unable to determine if the issue is in the way i am throwing exception .  Is there a way that I can mimic the producer failure  ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking the `currentAttempts=10, maxAttempts=9} exhausted for ` exception is expected after 10 retries - the default recoverer in the ARBP simply logs the error. You can add a custom recoverer, such as the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`. You shouldn't be using listener retries or a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with transactions (or any error handler at all) because it happens within the transaction, which will roll back. With transactions, the retry logic is performed in the `AfterRollbackProcessor`.

Comment: SeekToCurrentErrorHandler is part of the exponential retry logic which is triggered when we get error from 3rd party integration.  That is working as expected.  Based on the response from the 3rd party we are composing a new object which is passed to the 2nd topic.  we created a producer to push this response and commit offset manually.  The issue is I am not able to figure out how to address the error caused during producer failure, i manually added an exception to mimic producer failure. But when i do this it restarts the whole transaction by calling the 3rd party (which i m trying to avoid)

Comment: Your seek logic is incorrect (unless you only have one partition). You are only seeking the first record; any records from other topics/partitions in the list will be lost. But, as I said, you shouldn't be doing it there anyway (or confiiguring retry) because that all happens in the scope of the transaction. With transactions, the `AfterRollbackProcessor` performs the seeks after the rollback. The `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor can be configured with exponenrial back off. You can also classify which exceptions are not retryable.